# Any way to save HTML Form data to database without webserver/sql?

Tags: javascript, html, database, forms

So currently i'm buidling a local website within work.

one of the feature that needs to be built is a request submission form.

We originally had this email to a central mailbox but we want it to take the form data and save it to a database in this case Access.

Is there any possible way of doing this without using SQL or ASP ? As the website is being build on a local server for all members of staff to access.

In the end all I want to do is create a form the user can submit which is sent to a database. Is it possible or would it be better to stick with the email idea?

Comment: A local server IS a webserver

Comment: Sorry bad wording, i should have said its on a drive on the server. We can't create anything using SQL or ASP.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without a webserver'? The machine on which your app is hosted is your webserver. You can install SQL Server on to it, right?

Comment: You can use a non-sql db. Like mongodb or cassandra. Hence no sql. But... I'm sure that's not what you are looking for so... what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't due to the number of restrictions, its a fairly large company and the only way to have access to SQL would be to give ownership of the site to the gatekeepers here and that means they would totally redesign it.

Comment: If you have an http server and you can install things like PHP but not a database server, a possible solution would be to save the form data to a CSV or similar file, and then opening that file with Access or other software.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save data without a database server. Only thing can be done is cookies in javascript but these will not be available always and will never help you cause..

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to say that html/css is client side scripting language, without using server side language you can't save anything. You can use php or javascript(ajax) in order to do that.

Comment: We started to build a data access page in access. We were able to implement this into the website the submission was saved into the access database successfully but each time it's loaded it loads the previous entry not a new one. We were planning on just removing access to go backwards and delete in the form but is there any way to get it to automatically bring up a blank entry?

Comment: I  didn't get properly, do you want to delete entries?

Comment: No, we simply want the user to open the page to submit a request Fill the details out, which in turns submits the details and then leave that page. The only problem is however that if another user comes along they can see the previous entry.

Comment: I don't know how you are doing this but, why don't you use local server and try to implement this using php

Answer (score 0):

Only under Internet Explorer, you can save data into MS Access database for example using ActiveX. But html file must be open locally. 
Edit: 
 If needed I can write you a sample code.

Comment: The file would be opened locally, would it be possible for you to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are targeting Safari browsers, you can try using `IndexedDB`(http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb), a form of local storage supported by major browsers, with no size limit. It can be used carefully to emulate a remote database using a JavaScript [object relational mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Comment: That would have been great but as we understand not all of the computers are on internet explorer 10. Not all can be updated either as various areas use different systems.

Comment: You are testing on *your* local machine, are you not?

Comment: Yes but won't this mean users that are on the old browser won't be able to submit anything.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you a server :). If you don't want to use sql there are many ways to save data. The simplest would be to write a file on disk with what you need.